# Can't find Code Snippets Manager Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

According to this Visual Studio Docs page on [Code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2019), the Code Snippets Manager should be available in the tools menu in Visual Studio 2019. Why is it disabled?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Visual Studio 16.1.0 and it became enabled.